# Add exception to googleverifcation file using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, seo

recently I removed all the .html extension in our site 
using htaccess 
**here is my code:**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^\ ]+)\.html\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

I'm having problem in adding exception into it.
I would like to allow this file

`google4fa5440fdd1877e2.html`

I badly needed your inputs in it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !google4fa5440fdd1877e2\.html [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ (/[^.]+)\.html\  [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Please accept the answer whenever you can.